# Problema al cargar la imagen y el texto en un xml android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment

El principal problema es que cuando utilizo FrameLayout en el XML y le paso los parámetros [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No me muestra todo lo deseado, me muestra el texto del TextView pero no me muestra la imagen, esta imagen la estoy cargando desde la base de datos de firebase que le estoy poniendo una URL

Cuando cambio el Layout a LinearLayout me muestra la imagen pero no me muestra el texto, no se si sera porque la imagen se pone por encima del texto o porque será pero me estoy volviendo loco, si es así, como podría traer el texto al frente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a tu layout se muestra una imagen (`ImageView`) pero arriba de esta se muestra la vista (`View`) por lo tanto no se mostrara la imagen, al final se mostrara el `TextView` centrado.

Si deseas ver la imagen como en este ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la solución es eliminar la `View` ya que esta aparece arriba de la imagen.

---

Si estas usando un `Framelayout` para contener varias vistas, tienes como opción usar al menos un `LinearLayout` o `RelativeLayout` para contener los elementos, ejemplo:

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    ...
    >

 <!-- Contenedor de vistas -->

  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    ...
    ...
    >

    <ImageView
    ...
    ...
    />

    <View
     ...
    />

    <TextView
     ...
    />

  </LinearLayout>

 </FrameLayout>
```